.Net Maui Android emulator opens the app then gets stuck on "Waiting for the debugger to attach"
I am trying to run the .NET Maui app template with no changes. It should work out of the box. However in the emulator the app opens then sits on a popup that says "Waiting For Debugger" then "Application app name (process com.appname) is waiting for the debugger to attach.
Sometimes I can get it to work for a bit when I restart my PC. But obviously having to restart every time I make a code change is not a viable solution.
How do I attach the debugger?

Have you tried deleting your bin and obj directories?  Is Visual Studio up-to-date?  Have you tried checking if this application is installed on your PC and uninstalling it before re-launching VS + debugging (MAUI apps are installed when you debug them)?

Just started running into the exact same issue. I'll report back if I find anything. I've tried a couple different emulators so far with no success.

You may also refer to How to enable hardware acceleration with Android emulators (Hyper-V & AEHD).

It looks like this issue is when setting the Android package format to 'bundle', I changed it to 'apk' and it worked.

I set it back to 'bundle' before a Release.

First run the application from VisualStudio, this will install the app in emulator. If you get the error "Waiting for debugger" stop the application from Visual Studio. Next remove the application from emulator and launch the app again from VisualStudio. This time the error will show once and then it will automatically disappear and the application will run in emulator. This is how I fixed at my end.
